# Openpanel and symbol communication not working

Tags: puredata

I am trying to make a patch that plays audio when a bang is pressed. I have put a symbol so that I don't need to keep reimporting the file. However it works sometimes but not all the time.

A warning in the Pd console reads: `Start requested with no prior open`

However I have imported an audio file 

 Is there something that I have done wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[trigger]` to get the order-of-execution correct.

One problem is, that whenever you send a `[1(` to `[readsf~]` you must have sent an `[open ...(` message *directly* beforehand.
Even if you have just successfully opened a file, but then stopped it (with `[0(`) or played it through (so it has been closed automatically), you have to send the filename *again*.

The *real* problem is, that your messages are out of order: you should never have a *fan-out* (that is: connecting a message outlet to multiple inlets), as this will create *undefined behavior*.

Use `[trigger]` to get the order-of-execution correct.

(Mastering `[trigger]` is probably the single most important step in learning to program Pd)